# Префиксы в файлах ресурсов Qt

Tags: xml, qt, qt4

В одной библиотеке

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/prefix1">
        <file>folder/picture.png</file>
...
```

Во второй библиотеке

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/prefix2">
        <file>folder/picture.png</file>
...
```

Т.е. папки имеют одинаковые названия.
Нужно, чтобы одновременно в приложении можно было использовать:

```
 ":/prefix1/folder/picture.png"

":/prefix2/folder/picture.png"
```

Работает только вариант из библиотеки, которая линкуется раньше.

Comment: А файлы ресурсов случаем не одинаковые имена имеют?

Comment: @EvgenyShmidt, пока я ответ оформлял, вы тоже до разгадки дошли

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Немного неверно трактуете ситуацию:

> Работает только вариант из библиотеки, которая устанавливается раньше.

Правильнее будет так: подключаются ресурсы только из той библиотеки, что линкуется первой, т.е. указана выше в списке в `pro`-файле

```
LIBS += -llib1 \
        -llib2
```

Такая проблема возникает если исходные файлы `.qrc` обеих библиотек названы одинаково.

Решение проблемы простое: исходные файлы `.qrc` в ваших библиотеках должны иметь различающиеся имена.

Вот пример, где всё работает как вам надо:

```
// директория test:
lib1/
lib2/
main.cpp
test.pro

// директория lib1:
icons/
res.pro
icons1.qrc          // < Именуем не одинаково!

// директория lib2:
icons/
res.pro
icons2.qrc          // < Именуем не одинаково!

// директория lib1/icons:
ico1.png
ico12.png

// директория lib2/icons:
ico1.png
ico22.png

// lib1/res.pro:
TEMPLATE = lib
TARGET = lib1 
RESOURCES = icons1.qrc

// lib2/res.pro:
TEMPLATE = lib
TARGET = lib2 
RESOURCES = icons2.qrc

// test.pro:
TEMPLATE = app
SOURCES = main.cpp
LIBS += -llib1 \
        -llib2

// icons1.qrc:
<RCC>
  <qresource prefix="/lib1">
    <file>icons/ico1.png</file>
    <file>icons/ico12.png</file>
  </qresource>
</RCC>

// icons2.qrc:
<RCC>
  <qresource prefix="/lib2">
    <file>icons/ico1.png</file>
    <file>icons/ico22.png</file>
  </qresource>
</RCC>

// main.cpp:
#include <QApplication>
#include <QIcon>
#include <QLayout>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QWidget>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  QObject::connect(&app, SIGNAL(lastWindowClosed()), &app, SLOT(quit()));

  QWidget wgt;
  wgt.setLayout(new QVBoxLayout(&wgt));

  QPushButton* pb = new QPushButton(&wgt);
  pb->setIcon(QIcon(":/lib1/icons/ico1.png"));
  pb->setText(QString("lib1-ico1"));
  wgt.layout()->addWidget(pb);

  pb = new QPushButton(&wgt);
  pb->setIcon(QIcon(":/lib2/icons/ico1.png"));
  pb->setText(QString("lib2-ico1"));
  wgt.layout()->addWidget(pb);

  pb = new QPushButton(&wgt);
  pb->setIcon(QIcon(":/lib1/icons/ico12.png"));
  pb->setText(QString("lib1-ico12"));
  wgt.layout()->addWidget(pb);

  pb = new QPushButton(&wgt);
  pb->setIcon(QIcon(":/lib2/icons/ico22.png"));
  pb->setText(QString("lib2-ico22"));
  wgt.layout()->addWidget(pb);

  wgt.show();

  return app.exec();
}
```